# 20.04 lagging UI and Videos

Tags: 20.04

Upgrading 20.04 from 19.10 makes my Ubuntu almost unusable. User interface is lagging, even typing this text in textarea has noticeable delay.Youtube videos are lagging. I suspected wrong graphic drivers or problem with Xorg/Wayland. I tried to nouveau drivers and Nvidia 440 both the same. Both sessions are lagging on Xorg and on Wayland.

Nvidia-drivers 390 and 435 make Ubuntu freeze on booting